MVC Input Type Date Cannot Default Today's Date
I new to MVC Bootstrap 5 and am struggled to set the default date on the form with a datepicker calendar.
I have this HTML:
<input type="text" class="datepicker" value="@DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")" width="300" />

The above code rendered value as Today's date.

Since I can no longer use Jquery Datepicker with Bootstrap 5, I tried to change the input type to "date" to have a calendar picker next to the input, but then the default date is not working anymore (see screenshot below). Here is the HTML code that change only the input type to "date":
<input type="date" class="datepicker" value="@DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")" width="300" />

Then the textbox is no longer showing today's date, but it shows "mm/dd/yyyy" instead.

How can I default today's date in the textbox and also use the little calendar datepicker next to it?
